# Concluding by a density argument

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let 
$$
P^0:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)\\
P^1:(L^2(\Omega))^3\to (L^2(\Omega))^3
$$
be bounded operators.
In particular, the images of $P^0$ and $P^1$ are subsets of some suitable spline spaces.

We want to prove that
$$
\text{grad}\,(P^0 f)=P^1(\text{grad}\, f)\qquad \forall\,\, f\in H^1(\Omega).
$$
I proved the statement for every $f\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Then, I considered a convergent sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ such that $f_n\to f \in H^1(\Omega)$, where the convergence is wrt to $\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$.

I can't write down the density argument explicitly. Any help?

Comment: Why should $P^0 f$ be (weakly) differentiable? Or is it the distributional derivative?

Comment: Because its a spline. I forgot to say

Comment: Can you post $P^0$ and $P^1$? I really don't what you mean.